# Retrieve unique device ID

Tags: c#

What is the most unique ID of a device and how to retrieve it with a ManagementObjectCollection in C#?

```
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity"))
                collection = searcher.Get();

foreach (var valueString in from mo in collection.Cast<ManagementObject>()...
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the `"DeviceID"-property` from your ManagementObject.